# python - binding to a tkinter widget is called twice if set() is called on a StringVar()

Tags: python, data-binding, tkinter, binding, listbox

I have an entry, a listbox(dropdown) and another listbox. Whenever more than 3 characters are typed inside the entry. A completion list is looked up and inserted to the dropdown and the dropdown is shown. If an item is selected from the dropdown. It's value should fill the entry and the entry should get the focus again and the cursor should go to the end of the entry. And then, when Enter key is pressed the value of the entry should be inserted to the other listbox.

I've developed a code for that with much help from [this](https://github.com/Coal0/Utilities/tree/master/tkinter_autocomplete) utility and the code works perfectly fine. Except, I realized that whenever I select an option from the dropdown the corresponding method is called twice(I get two prints in the console from the same thing). But if I select the first option of the dropdown, it's called once(which is what should have actually happened in the other case) but the focus does not go to the entry (which is a problem).

**Here is my code:**

```
from tkinter import *


class Autocomplete(Frame, object):
    def __init__(self, width, height, entries, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Autocomplete, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._entries = entries
        self.listbox_height = height
        self.entry_width = width
        self.text = StringVar()
        self.entry = Entry(
            self,
            textvariable=self.text,
            width=self.entry_width
        )
        self.frame = Frame(self)
        self.listbox = Listbox(
            self.frame,
            height=self.listbox_height,
            width=self.entry_width
        )
        self.dropdown = Listbox(
            self.frame,
            height=self.listbox_height,
            width=self.entry_width,
            background="#cfeff9"
        )

    def build(self):
        self.text.trace("w", lambda name, index, mode, text=self.text: self._update_autocomplete())
        self.entry.bind("<Return>", lambda event,: self._add_course())
        self.entry.focus_set()
        self.entry.pack()
        self.frame.pack()
        self.listbox.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=N)
        self.dropdown.bind("<<ListboxSelect>>", self._select_entry)
        self.dropdown.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=N)
        self.dropdown.grid_forget()
        return self

    def _update_autocomplete(self):
        self.dropdown["height"] = self.listbox_height
        self.dropdown.delete(0, END)
        text = self.text.get()
        if len(text) < 3:
            self.dropdown.grid_forget()
            return
        else:
            for entry in self._entries:
                if text.lower() in entry.strip().lower():
                    self.dropdown.insert(END, entry)
        listbox_size = self.dropdown.size()
        if not listbox_size:
            self.dropdown.insert(END, "No results found for '{}'")
            self.dropdown["height"] = 1
        else:
            if listbox_size <= self.dropdown["height"]:
                self.dropdown["height"] = listbox_size
        self.dropdown.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=N)

    def _select_entry(self, event):
        widget = event.widget
        value = widget.get(int(widget.curselection()[0]))
        print(value)
        self.text.set(value)
        self.entry.focus_set()
        self.entry.icursor(END)

    def _add_course(self):
        self.listbox.insert(END, self.text.get())
```

So what am I missing here?

By the way any general improvement to the code will also be much appreciated.

And here is how I call it:

```
from tkinter import *
from autocomplete import Autocomplete
from main import *

courses = load_courses_from_file("courses.txt")
root = Tk()
autocomplete_frame = Autocomplete(
    60,
    10,
    list(set(course.name + ", " + course.instructor for course in courses))
).build().pack()
mainloop()
```

Comment: Your code won't run as posted.

Comment: @BryanOakley What do you mean? do you mean that I haven't called it? if so I edited the post. Otherwise, Are you sure? bc I think I'm running it and i think i copy pasted the code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The selection of the listbox changes when you click on the item -- this is the default behavior of the listbox. This causes the entry widget value to change, which triggers a call to `_update_autocomplete`. That function deletes everything in the listbox, causing the selection to change again.

Comment: I see! And when the first one is clicked the number of the selected element stays 1 so it doesn't change. Though I still don't get why the focus is not changed. And how I should fix that.